# how to pass curl --user through rest-assured

Tags: rest-assured

Below is the cURL

```
curl --user name:passwoed -k -X POST \
  https://test_url/oauth/token \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  -d grant_type=client_credentials
```

I tried below but getting 400

```
given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
     auth().basic("name", "password").
when().
     post("https://test_url/oauth/token").
then().
     statusCode(200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution
Note, I was not passing data earlier

```
 given().relaxedHTTPSValidation().
       auth().basic("name", "password").
       param("grant_type","client_credentials").
 when().
       post("https://test_url/oauth/token").
 then().
       statusCode(200);
```